# Import row A2 from tab within Sheet in Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a set of data that imports via Google Sheets Script Editor into Sheet1, when it finishes I wish to insert a header above the data into Sheet1 - this row is stored in an adjacent tab called Header. In Row 1

What script command is needed to insert from another tab within the Google Script Editor?

So something like IMPORTRANGE with the Tab name (header) and required row (1) to be inserted into Sheet 1 at position 1 (the first row)

[image]

Comment: show us your script

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var header = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Header");
var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var last = header.getLastColumn(); 

var a = header.getRange(1, 1, 1, last).getValues();
var b = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, last);

b.setValues(a);
```

Please, can you let me know if It works out?